# beginners guide to Amazon Web Services (EC2, S3, RDS, EBS etc)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Ive been delving into the world of AWS and, with very little server management experience under my belt, I'm quickly getting lost!

I'm looking at creating a system that uses Route 53, Elastic Load Balancing, EC2, RDS, S3 (possibly with CloudFront as well) so I can host a user generated content website that also streams video.

So Ive been looking at the following books:

[Host Your Web Site On The Cloud: Amazon Web Services Made Easy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Host-Your-Web-Site-Cloud/dp/0980576830/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326198073&sr=8-1)

[Programming Amazon Web Services: S3, EC2, SQS, FPS, and SimpleDB](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Amazon-Web-Services-SimpleDB/dp/0596515812/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=1326198095&sr=8-3)

[Programming Amazon EC2: Run Applications on Amazon's Infrastructure with EC2, S3, SQS, SimpleDB, and Other Services](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Amazon-EC2-Applications-Infrastructure/dp/1449393683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326198095&sr=8-1)

If I had to go for one of these what would you recommend?

Most importantly are there any resources you can recommend for a newbie like myself to quickly learn and understand the nuances to AWS?

TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although all of those resources are good, the best way to dive into using AWS is in my experience [CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/). With CloudFormation you are able to script most if not all of your AWS resources in a single json script. By writing your cloudformation scripts and looking through the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) and [sample scripts](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/), you will start to get aquatinted with how all of the AWS toolsets work.

> Most importantly are there any resources you can reconmend for a
>   newbie like myself to quickly learn and understand the nuances to AWS?

As mentioned above, CloudFormation

However to make sure I answer your question:

> If I had to go for one of these what would you recommend?

I have read all 3 resources listed and I found [Programming EC2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Amazon-EC2-Applications-Infrastructure/dp/1449393683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1326198095&sr=8-1) to be the most useful in understanding the AWS toolset

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Ive managed to figure out quite a bit of AWS since I asked this question, and have mostly avoided CloudFormation, but I am guessing Ive learned AWS the hard way and your answer will be good for anybody else who is in a similar position to where I was back then.

Comment: can you explain me how aws works. If i am not wrong the minimum cost of aws comes around $30 per month. And i don't get how you actually use it beside ssh which is fine but i was thinking maybe there are other ways. Also it's like every 5 months new aws service is announced.

Comment: also i checked out google cloud platform it seemed little bit cheaper. 15 instead of 30